# F# generics: can I constrain a type to not be "unit"?

Tags: generics, f#, constraints

I'm currently teaching myself F#, and have come across this need a few times so I thought it was time to get an answer.

Essentially I would like a function to be generic and to work with every type **except unit**. In the most recent case I'm writing a function that will wrap any other function and cache its result in the given concurrent dictionary. My code so far is as follows:

```
type CacheStore = System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<Guid * obj, DateTime * obj>

let (|ItemPresent|ItemExpired|ItemNotPresent|) ((cacheStore : CacheStore), cacheKey) =
    if cacheStore.ContainsKey cacheKey
    then
        let expiryTime, value = cacheStore.[cacheKey]
        if expiryTime > DateTime.Now
        then ItemPresent value
        else ItemExpired (DateTime.Now - expiryTime)
    else ItemNotPresent

let cache<'a, 'b> (cacheStore : CacheStore) (functionToCache : 'a -> 'b) =
    let functionId = Guid.NewGuid()

    let updateCache (cacheStore : CacheStore) cacheKey newValue =
        printfn "Updating cache"
        cacheStore.[cacheKey] <- ((DateTime.Now.AddSeconds 1.0), box newValue)
        newValue

    fun arg ->
        let cacheKey = functionId, (box arg)

        match cacheStore, cacheKey with
        | ItemPresent value ->
            printfn "Retrieving from cache"
            value :?> 'b
        | ItemExpired ago ->
            printfn "Item in cache but expired %A ago; running function" ago
            updateCache cacheStore cacheKey (functionToCache arg)
        | ItemNotPresent ->
            printfn "Item not in cache; running function."
            updateCache cacheStore cacheKey (functionToCache arg)
```

Obviously, it makes no sense to cache a function that is void / returns unit, <s>and in fact this code will fail at runtime if someone tries to cache a 'a -> unit function.</s>

How do I make it fail at compiletime if someone calls this incorrectly? From what I've read I feel that I should be able to do this with an inline function and static type constraints but I don't know how to write that...

**UPDATE**
I have since found that this particular version actually *does* work with unit functions - the cache wrapper essentially has no effect (it just adds runtime overhead), but the gist of the original question still stands: can I stop people calling this function with unit functions?

Comment: Thanks for trying it out Daniel - I guess that in this case it's academic but still interesting. I have written higher order functions before that throw exceptions when passed unit-returning functions and would be interested to know if I can prevent it in future.

Comment: Since `unit` is a normal type ([see source](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L27-34)) I don't think there's a way to do this without placing excessive constraints on the type arg.

Comment: One option (which might be too restrictive) is to use the constraint `'b when 'b : struct`.

Comment: Another option is `'b when 'b :> System.Collections.IStructuralEquatable` which would work for DUs and records. I don't see a way of excluding `unit` without narrowly defining the acceptable types.

Comment: @Daniel It's interesting now that you point to the source and mention that Unit is a normal type. I see that it provides overrides for the members of Object... So why does `().GetHashCode()` throw a NRE?

Comment: F# sometimes represents `()` as null at runtime. But, for purposes of typing, `unit` is a plain ol' class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no good way to do this, and I'd recommend against trying to.  `unit` is just a type with a single value (`()`) - why treat this one type in any special way?  Your function won't break when used with a `unit` returning function, so why not trust your callers not to use it if it doesn't provide any benefit?  And if your callers are trying to use your function in a generic way, then any restriction you place on your function will propagate to them, which may also be undesired.

Comment: You're right, except for the irritating reality that `()` is implemented as null at run time. In the original version of my code, which had a signature like `cache store f arg` I was calling `arg.GetHashCode()` at some point. If you wrapped a unit function then you would get a NRE when you tried to call the wrapped version because `().GetHashCode()` throws an exception. Frustrating.

Comment: @Richiban: That's easy enough to handle: `match arg with null -> 0 | _ -> arg.GetHashCode()`. The good thing about that approach is it handles the more general case of _null references_ as opposed to the one-off case of `unit`.

Comment: @Daniel I don't think that this is a good idea: `match arg with null -> 0 | _ -> arg.GetHashCode()`, as won't this add the constraint "requires 'a : null" to my cache function?

Comment: Yes, sorry, boxing will avoid the constraint: `match box arg with null -> ...`

Comment: @Richiban - generally, you should use `hash arg` rather than `arg.GetHashCode()`, since this works around these problematic representation issues (you'd also see this with `(None : int option).GetHashCode()` for instance).

Comment: @Richiban: re: kvb's comment, it's worth noting that `hash` performs _structural_ hashing, so you will observe different behavior than `GetHashCode()` for some types, most notably arrays.

Comment: By the way, avoiding `unit` wouldn't have completely worked around this anyway, since there are other values that are represented as `null` (notably, `None`).